# Starting a mule flow programmatically using groovy

Tags: groovy, mule

I need to control the execution of a flow manually through a HTTP call.

I have been told I can disable the flow from executing during startup using the `initialState="stopped"` attribute on the flow. ([How to stop a mule flow from running after startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387745/how-to-stop-a-mule-flow-from-running-after-startup))

I need to know how to start the flow back using a groovy script.

Using mule 3.2.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Comment: Is there a way to "pass" a value to the flow? E.g., looping through a list of strings, starting the same flow for each one, and using that string in the flow (like a value to pass to an HTTP endpoint)? I'll ask in a new question as well since my use case is probably better-solved some other way.

Comment: You can use a collection splitter to generate N messages out of the collection of strings and pass them to the processing flow.