# auto-starting Mule flow

Tags: groovy, mule

I'm trying this approach to autostart a Mule flow

[Starting a mule flow programmatically using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394475/starting-a-mule-flow-programmatically-using-groovy)

and it does not start the flow. Here's a very simple test run in Mule Studio with the 3.4.0 CE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"     
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">

<flow name="auto2Flow1" doc:name="auto2Flow1">
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
             muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('flow1').start()
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
</flow>

<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="hello"/>
</flow>

</mule>
```

I also tried this with no luck

```
<expression-component>
   app.registry.flow1.start();
</expression-component>
```

I'm assuming flow1 is automatically registered but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is not *starting* the flow but instead send an event to it so, in your case, you'll see the `logger` write out `hello`.

For this, use:

```
app.registry.flow1.process(event);
```

with 'event' being an instance of `DefaultMuleEvent` ([javadoc](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/DefaultMuleEvent.html)).

Comment: In my example I want auto2Flow1 to start upon Mule server startup. It should call flow1 which is the main flow. I tried replacing my muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct with your statement but obviously I am missing something as that did not work.

Comment: Oh, that's completely different from your question. You want `auto2Flow1` to be triggered with an event when Mule starts then? I don't think there's anything for that. Just use an `init-method` on a `MuleContextAware` Spring bean and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Flows are automatically started, you don't need to "run" them.

Messages will be processed depending on the message sources you have in your flows, which are the ones triggering the flow execution.

I would suggest you to carefully read the documentation: 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Application+Architecture

Answer (score 0):

You should not start the flow manually. Once you deployed your mule application locally or in cloud or on premise the flow will start automatically.
If you would like to stop the flow or freeze the flow for some time then you can use some groovy Script something like sleep(1000); for some time

Answer (score 0):

This way you can start/stop your flow programmatically by using groovy component

```
<scripting:component doc:name="start/stop the flows">
<scripting:script engine="Groovy">
<![CDATA[muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('my-Flow-1').start();
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('my-Flow-2').start();
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('myFlow-3').stop();
]]></scripting:script></scripting:component>
```