# Mule - Start a Stopped default flow

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-flow

I have a two `mule flows`, one of them is `stopped` by default.

I want to start that flow when I want although the application is started.

I've been looking this post: [Starting a mule flow programmatically using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394475/starting-a-mule-flow-programmatically-using-groovy)
But how can I execute in Windows Server that command? I don't understand it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "command" is really a component of Mule: Groovy.

You can learn more in

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/groovy-component-reference

Comment: But.. How can I call to that compand with Groovy in Windows?

Comment: It's not a command. It is a Mule Component. Regardless of S.O, it will run in the same way