# Invoke mule 3 file transport once event is received

Tags: mule

I use mule 3.3.1 CE.

I have a scenario to read *.json files from a backup directory when the message payload is SUCCESS string.

Here is my mule-config:

---

```
<flow>
    ...
    <flow-ref name="auditTrailFlow"/>
    <flow-ref name="auditTrailBackupFlow"/>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="auditTrailBackupFlow">
 /// returns SUCCESS
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="auditTrailBackupFlow">
            <description>
                Resending backup AuditTrail JSON's objects to db
            </description>
            <choice>
                <when expression="#[message.payload == SUCCESS]">
                    <logger level="INFO" message="Checking audittrail backup directory"/>
                    <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="in" path="${audittrail.backup.dir}">
                        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json" caseSensitive="true" />
                    </file:inbound-endpoint>
                    <not-filter>
                        <filter ref="nullPayloadFilter"/>
                    </not-filter>
                    <json:json-to-object-transformer targetClass="com.company.AuditTrail"/>
                    // updates db
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    // do something
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

I get the following error when app deploys in server

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:inbound-endpoint'.
```

Based on the error , I understand that file:inbound-endpoint is in the wrong location.

My question is how do I tell mule file transport to read files once the mule message payload is SUCCESS.

Comment: When do you want the `file:inbound-endpoint` to stop reading JSON files from the designated directory? Do you have another event to make it stop?

Comment: @DavidDossot It stops once the directory is empty. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: An inbound endpoint keeps polling for ever, it doesn't stop polling when the directory is empty.

Comment: BTW `#[message.payload == 'SUCCESS']` is probably what you want (you're missing the `'` around SUCCESS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an inbound endpoint amid flow as you're trying to do. Inbound endpoints are message sources and, as such, must be placed at the beginning of the flow.

There are many viable options to solve your problem, but the two ones I would recommend are these:

- Put the file inbound endpoint in a flow that is initialized stopped and start/stop this flow using the approach shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389312/387927 The problem is that you need to find out a good time to stop the flow, maybe by having another flow acting as a watcher on the directory.
- Replace the file inbound endpoint in the above configuration with a custom component (Java or scripted) that programmatically use the MuleClient to `request()` files from the target directory and dispatch these files to another flow in charge of processing them.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the flow is already started similar to the one you posted here                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387745/how-to-stop-a-mule-flow-from-running-after-startup/15389312#15389312

Comment: Yep! There is an `isStarted()` method on `org.mule.construct.Flow`: http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/construct/Flow.html

Comment: I implemented the 1st recommendation and it worked.Thanks for your support.