# mule with wmq--how to fetch message from queue in fifo manner

Tags: mule

I have a flow with wmq, java transformer , and file endpoint.

The issue is wma is not fetching the message serially. Wmq is randomly picks the message and after java transformation, puts in a folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your queue configured correctly?

> **MSGDLVSQ(FIFO)**
>
> Otherwise, messages will be processed in priority sequence.

Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqsav.doc/zs11430_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.0.1%2F1-31-3-1-1&lang=en

Comment: yes, the queue is configured properly. Its properties set to FIFO.Please provide me any other solution. Its very urgent for me

Comment: Will correlation iD help out in this situation?? If yes, Then could you please tell me how to set correlation ID in my flow??

Comment: No, correlation ID won't help. Making your flow synchronous may help because what may happen is that messages are consumed in order but written to disk OOO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300735/mule-issue-if-multiple-flows-in-one-project/24349092?noredirect=1#comment37652351_24349092

Comment: Please find the flow xml from the above link. I have used asynchronous strategy because first i want to run one thread at a time. Should i replace it with synchronous??

Comment: This XML config doesn't have any `file:outbound-endpoint`... Anyway, using asynchronous strategy does the opposite of what you want: if you want a single thread, go synchronous.

Comment: What is the difference between two? Could u explain by a example

Comment: Take a look a this: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies

Comment: using synchronous is not working for me. I just want to execute first my whole flow for first input and then inbound endpoint allowed to get another input and execute it. If i am using synchronous, then all the input is coming in the java transformer node at once